# How to create a tileset of custom size in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

I am trying to create a tileset of size 200X200. But by default it builts 256X256 tiles. The documentation says, the settings is available under gridsets. So I tried creating a new gridset with the tile size of 200X200.

But where do I use this gridset when creating the tiles?

In the tile creation page, the dropdown to select the gridset, does not list the newly created gridset.

Comment: can you look in the log file to see if creating the gird set fails? also which version are you using.